# problem installing civicrm 4.7 on Wordpress 4.5

Tags: wordpress, installation, 4.7

According to my hosting company failure  is being caused by a code fault within the CiviCRM plugin itself, the following fatal error is being returned:
Fatal error: Call to a member function register() on a non-object in /home/chichest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 95

They say the CiviCRM plugin's developers,  should be able to provide details on exactly why their software is erroring.

Comment: You (or your hosting company) needs to provide more details on the installation process followed. The error cited is a line of code where CiviCRM is trying to load a CiviCRM extension. Did you ever have the site working? What recipe was followed for the installation?

Comment: I followed guidance at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5# and gto to stage 5 activiating Civicrm, but on clicking on the Civicrm option just under the wordpress dashboard got the message 'The chichestersociety.org.uk page isn’t working.chichestersociety.org.uk is currently unable to handle this request.500" On the edit page for each post or page there is  'civicrm' button next to each 'add media' button and on clicking it the page shown is blank. My hosting Co said the reason is as mentioned above

Comment: Subsequently I deleted civicrm plugin and started again extracting the download in the plugin directory. I got to the point where the CRM Installer screen was showing the message 'You're ready to install'  So I ticked the option 'load sample data' and then selected 'Check requirements and install' but got the screen message 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'.Then  I find that I cannot edit posts or pages as I get the message 'The chichestersociety.org.uk page isn’t working 
and is  unable to handle this request. 
500' And I can't now get the installer screen again

Comment: I got my hosting company to follow the same procedure as I did and they reported back as follows:it seems to be throwing a completely different error this time, but again points to a coding problem with the CRM, as per this output;

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. thrown in /home/chichest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 53

 Use of different PHP versions did not fix this error

Comment: My hosting company thinks the problem may relate to conflict with an existing plugin and cannot find a solution. We wanted to use this plugin to manage Society membership and subscription details which are currently managed using Excel spreadsheets. Given the problem of even getting Civicrm loaded I think we will stay with spreadsheets!